# Serva Windows 8 Install: Network location cannot be reached?

Tags: networking, windows-8, lan, pxe

I have a Toshiba z30-a1301 that I am trying to install Windows 8 on. The only way I am able to do it is through LAN boot. (No option for USB, no CD slot, no recovery partition).

I'm using Serva, and surprisingly enough all the automatic settings seem to be working for me. DHCP and TFTP goes through and I reach the ServaPENet window with console access as well.

I get an "OK" for both oem network drivers install and loading network resources
Unfortunately I cannot go past that. It asks for me to input my username and password to connect to Serva's WIA, but the same error always comes up:

> - 0x4cf the network location cannot be reached.

I've done as much troubleshooting as I could, the WDA folder is shared and access is given, its named correctly too.

One thing I've noticed, in the console when I type the command IPCONFIG, I get basically nothing. Could this mean I just haven't found the right drivers yet? Or is this normal at this stage?

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the issue somehow.

I found a version of Windows 8.1 instead of the original Windows 8 image I had. After using this new version, the whole thing went smoothly.

I can only assume it is because the drivers for the newer hardware was not included in the older Windows 8 image I had.

Comment: You are right; there are situations where network driver errors are not correctly reported in Windows PE (ServaPENet) then the mapping action returns things like `The network location cannot be reached` but the problem is just a buggy/missing NIC driver.

Comment: I can absolutely confirm this. A quick way to check if it's the case, is opening the console and running `ipconfig`. If there's no IP and device then windows is missing your drivers. Adding them is [as easy](https://www.vercot.com/~serva/an/WindowsPXE1.html#troubleshooting) as it could get with Serva, but make sure to have the 32-bit server executable if you are booting a 32-bit OS, and viceversa with 64-bit.